# Adding different min max attribute value to respective input fields using same ng model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, max, min

Issue : On entering amount on the second input field its not taking values between 50000 and 750000, as soon as I start typing 500000, it clears out the values. It is accepting anything below 50000 and above 75000

Expected behavior: I want first input field to take range between 75000 and max value (which is working)and second field to take between 50000 and max value. (first input field is overriding second one in my case)

I am using same ng-model for below input fields as the purpose of both the field is same but based on certain criteria I want to show and hide these fields and display different label and min max attribute.

I also have directive check-amount that validates min max values entered and popover the error message

```
<div ng-hide="selection==1">
<label name="test">what is the amount?</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="test" min="75000" max="1000000" check-amount name="test" id="test" data-placement="bottom"  data-content="Amount should be between: $75,000 and $1,000,000">
</div>
<div ng-show="selection==1">
<label name="test">how much you want to enter?</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="test" min="50000" max="1000000" check-amount name="test" id="test" data-placement="bottom"  data-content="Amount should be between: $50,000 and $1,000,000">
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a plunker for your issue scenario?

Comment: You should use `type= "number"` instead of `"text"`.